# How a consumer will read committed messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-transactions-api

So, as far as I understand from [Transactions in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/), a *read_committed* consumer will not return the messages which are part of an ongoing transaction. So, I guess, the consumer will have the option to commit its offset past those ongoing-transaction messages (e.g. to read non-transactional messages) or the option to make no further advancement until the encountered transaction is committed/aborted. I just suppose it will be allowed (by Kafka) to skip those pending-transaction records, but then how the consumer will read them when committed considering that its offset might already be far away?

**UPDATE**

Consider that the topic could have a mix of records (aka messages) coming from non-transactional producers and transactional ones. E.g., consider this *partition* from a topic:

non-transact-Xmsg, from-transact-producer1-msg, from-transact-producer2-msg, non-transact-Ymsg

If the *consumer* encounters *from-transact-producer1-msg* will he skip the message then read *non-transact-Ymsg* or will he just hang before the not yet committed *from-transact-producer1-msg* and by doing so it won't read *non-transact-Ymsg*?

Consider also that could be many transactional producers and so many equivalents of *from-transact-producer1-msg*, some committed some not. So, *from-transact-producer2-msg* could be a committed one at the point when the consumer reached *non-transact-Xmsg*.

Comment: In the same Confluent blog it is stated _"...the consumer does not need to [sic] any buffering to wait for transactions to complete. Instead, **the broker does not allow it to advance to offsets which include open transactions.**"_

Comment: And that part puzzles me because it doesn't say that the consumer is not allowed to skip *pending transaction records* in order to read e.g. *non-transaction records*. But then what will happen when the *pending transaction records* become committed? Will they remain not read because were skipped when they were *pending*? Will the consumer go somehow automatically back? None of these make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs about [`isolation.level`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> Messages will always be returned in offset order. Hence, in `read_committed` mode, `consumer.poll()` will only return messages up to the `last stable offset (LSO)`, which is the one less than the offset of the first open transaction. **In particular any messages appearing after messages belonging to ongoing transactions will be withheld until the relevant transaction has been completed.** As a result, `read_committed` consumers will not be able to read up to the high watermark when there are in flight transactions.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE which highlights the possibility of having a mix of transaction-based or non-transaction-based records (aka messages) in a partition from a topic plus many transactional producers with their records also mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not 100% clear, but if I get it right, you want to be able to re-process some consumed messages that for some reason you could not successfully process when consuming them for the first time. And-  you don't want to get "stuck" on those messages, you prefer moving on and handle those later. 
In that case, the best option would probably be writing them to a **different** queue, and have another consumer read those "failed" messages and retry as much as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks but the question is about kafka transactions and the consumer filtering uncommitted ones while still advancing. At some point the consumer should return the committed transaction too but how? he already advanced (its kafka offset) past the now committed transactions.